# Cant use state param in google oauth using passport.js

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js, google-api-nodejs-client, passport-google-oauth

I have been trying to use `state` parameter in google oauth using passport.js but for some reason there is no state param on authentication url.My code

```
app.get('api/auth/google', passport.authenticate('google', {
      scope:[
        'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile',
        'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email'
      ],
      state: base64url(JSON.stringify({'kk':'vv'})),
  }));
```

And passport.js code

```
passport.use(new GoogleStrategy({
        clientID: 'id',
        clientSecret: 'secret',
        callbackURL: 'callback',
        passReqToCallback: true,
    },function(req,accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done){
          console.log(req.query.state);
     }

));
```

Output on console is `undefined`.I have read other post which said to use base64url encoding but still.